# What is the difference between diffeomorphism and isomorphism?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, analysis

What is the difference between diffeomorphisms and isomorphisms? I know isomorphisms already from my abstract algebra/group theory course, and now I'm studying analysis on (sub)manifolds, where this definition is new for me. Can anybody explain what the difference between the two is? Or in other words: how can I relate those two concepts? Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Diffeomorphism is simply a special name given to the concept of an "isomorphism of smooth manifolds".

In general, you will meet the concept of an isomorphism in many different areas. It denotes a mapping which identifies two different objects (i.e. they are basically the same object  in the category you are treating).

Answer (score 7):

"Isomorphism" is a word with many different meanings, you shouldn't use it without context. In context of groups it means a group homomorphism that is bijective, in the context of topological spaces we might use it as another word for homeomorphism, which is a bijective continuous map with continuous inverse.

"Diffeomorphism" on the other hand is a very well defined word. It is a bijective continuously differentiable map with continuously differentiable inverse. To talk about "continuous differentiability" we at least need the structure of $C^1$-manifolds.